# Unmet core-js dependency in Ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, npm, ionic2

I'm starting a new ionic 2 project and I'm trying to add https://github.com/afrad/angular2-websocket. When I install it, I get the following warning:

UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY core-js@^2.4.1

Ionic 2's template projects don't include it. I understand it's a polyfill project, but ionic already includes some sort of polyfill in it's builds. Is it really necessary to add this dependency to my project?

Answer (score 0):

no if you already installed other version of core-js. it's a warning, just ignore it.